# Is there a way to intercept a HTML file and change it before it reaches the browser, in Angular 2+

Tags: html, angular

I want to intercept the HTML files in an Angular app, so I can add an attribute to all (okay some) of the elements in the view i.e.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" />
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

becomes

```
<form>
   <input data-id="*componentName*.*elementName*" type="text" />
   <button data-id="*componentName*.*elementName*" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

where *componentName* and *elementName* are created dynamically.

Preferably a service so I don't need to alter existing code.

I've looked all over the tinternet but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I don't undestand, if it's an angular app, you can change the html of the component, what's the issue ? there is no such thing as an HTML file in an angular app, aside from the original html that loads the app. And since it's javascript there is no such thing as ```before it reaches the browser``` it's executed on the browser side anyway so it's already on the browser

Comment: Check the angular lifecycle hooks. Before binding the properties to template you can play with them in some hooks. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence

Comment: Sorry my terminology is wrong.